# iPhone / iPod Touch icon image error (MininumOSVersion is below 3.2) while project is for iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios5, warnings, xcode4.2, app-store-connect

I get this error while archiving (For upload to iTunes connect!):

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  Your MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2, so you must define CFBundleIconFile or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57. (-19013)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

But this is a **IPAD** app!!!

Comment: What are your Deployment Target settings?

Comment: iOS 5.0 it says on deployment target!

Comment: And, the MinimumOSVersion should NOT be set in the info.plist - Xcode should take care of that for you - so, finally, if there is no MinimumOSVersion in your info.plist, your Base SDK is set to Latest iOS, your Project Deployment Target is set to 5.0, and your Target Deployment Target is set to 5.0, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a `icon.png` 57 X 57 and set it as icon in `info.plist` and it worked!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In order to get it to work, I had to make a Icon.png which was 57x57 and the "I" had to be caps.  Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Your MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2"

If this is an iPad app then your minimum OS version should be 3.2, not below it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2, and iPad didn't exist before 3.2, so it expects an icon for iPhone running iOS 2+.

Comment: Still the same error maybe i'm setting the MinimumOSVersion in the wrong place. Currently i changed it in `info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your MinimumOSVersion? The iPad requires at least 3.2, but the error message says yours is "below 3.2".

In your Deployment Target settings, ensure that the correct version is selected (3.2 or above) in both Project and Targets.

I also suggest in your build settings to set the Base SDK to 'Latest iOS'. (Not related to this problem, probably, but helpful in future updates of your project.)

Comment: iOS 5.0 it says on deployment target!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the iOS "Deployment Target" in your Project's build settings as "iOS 3.2".
you should not get this issue after that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "icon.png" to "Icon.png" worked for me. Watch the caps.